# initramfs - fsck every time I boot 16.04?

Tags: boot, partitioning, xubuntu, ssd, fsck

I have fresh installed xubuntu on **SSD**, but almost after every boot I get this error.

```
initramfs - the root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires manual fsck
```

Yes the problem get temporally resolved buy running.

```
fsck /dev/sda1 -y
```

I have tried other solutions from askubunt but this is something that is happening too frequently almost after every boot.

Details of my SSD filesystem

[image]

Comment: Are you shutting Ubuntu down properly or do you just switch of you computer or cut the power supply? Did you boot a different operating system before every appearance of that error message? Those are the most common reasons I know.